# Условия выбора чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, checkbox

У нас есть сколько угодно чекбоксов. Допустим их 6. Все кроме последнего можно выбирать одновременно, т.е. любое количество от 1 и до 5. Но если выбрать последний чекбокс, то все остальные чекбоксы кроме последнего должны заблокироваться и чекет с них должен убраться. Если выбран последний чекбокс, то отправить можно только его одного. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Это реализовать кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Отловите событие change последнего чекбокса, а в обработчике пропишите проверку его состояния со всеми нужными последствиями:

```
<div class='checkboxes_cont'>
    ...
    ...
    <input type='checkbox' onchange='func()'>
</div
```

```
const func=(event)=>{
    if (event.target.checked) {
        Array.from(event.target.parentNode.children).forEach(item=>{item.checked = false; item.disabled = true});
    } else {
        Array.from(event.target.parentNode.children).forEach(item=>{item.disabled = false});
    };
}
```